Build Process Hangs When Accessing context.Request.Path in Middleware During Compilation for a .NET 8 App
I'm encountering a strange issue while building my ASP.NET Core application. The build process hangs indefinitely whenever I include code that accesses the context.Request.Path property in a middleware. However, the application runs fine when debugging.
Problem Details:
I have a middleware that modifies the request path when a 404 status code is returned, so it renders a custom 404 page without changing the URL. Here’s the middleware code:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        LogUtils.GetGlobalErrorLogger().Warn("Page not found: {PageUrl}", context.Request.GetDisplayUrl());
        context.Request.Path = "/404";  // This line causes the issue
        await next();
    }
});

When I build the project, the build process hangs while invoking the csc.exe compiler. Visual Studio remains responsive, but the build output stays on the same command indefinitely. I even left it running overnight without any progress. The same issue happens when running msbuild directly from command line.
Interestingly, the application starts up just fine when I use "Start Debugging." The issue seems specific to the build process.
Observations:
The hang occurs whenever I access context.Request.Path. Simply reading the property, without modifying it, is enough to cause the problem:
var path = context.Request.Path;  // Causes the hang

The middleware is only registered when the environment isn't Development, but the build is running under the Development environment.
Update:
Moving the logic to a class-based middleware seems to be working fine.
